# Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer how to resolve this problem in soapclient?

Tags: wsdl, soap-client, wsdl2java

Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer;

Comment: Reported a ticket on this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-6059

Answer (score 0):

Likely your application is just missing class "org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSServiceBuilderExtension". Or you switch your logging level to "debug" mode to see the detail stack traces. Good luck.